# Animate CC How can i cache as bitmap movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a movie clip (enemy) inside the enemy i have 3 frames for iddle, attack and   run.The enemies are inside Array.What is the better way to cache as bitmap the   enemy and movie clips inside the enemy?

```
    var greengoblinVelocity: int = 0;

var e: int;
for (e = numChildren - 1; e >= 0; e--)
{
var childdE: DisplayObject = getChildAt(e);
if (childdE.name.indexOf("enemy") > -1)
{
    GreenGoblinArray.push(MovieClip(childdE));
    MovieClip(childdE).hitPoints = 2;
    MovieClip(childdE).currentX = 0;
    MovieClip(childdE).startAttack = 0;
 }
}


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
function gameloop(event: Event): void
{
for (var enl = 0; enl < GreenGoblinArray.length; enl++)
    {
        var enemy: Enemy = GreenGoblinArray[enl] as Enemy;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can do `for (var e:int = numChildren; e >= 0; e--){`

Comment: What makes you think caching as bitmap is necessary? Smells like premature optimisation.

Comment: Its for mobile devices and i read that if i cash as bitmap all the objects in the stage the game running better.Because now i have lag problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatirx always sucked. There are few areas where you want to do it instead of just simply drawing to a bitmap. What render mode are you using? Thats important

Comment: I use CPU.Its ok or i need to change it?

Comment: If you are using mobile devices, you want to use the GPU. I suggest asking on the adobe air forums, but i believe pretty much no one uses cpu mode on mobile at all. Your options are rendermode gpu, or direct. Starling framwork using direct rendermode (stage 3d) is widely excepted as the best option. Rendermode gpu was supposed to be depreciated but never was, it does still work. If using that you want to use a technique where you have a bitmap, and you cycle though an array of bitmapDatas as its frames. More explanation here  http://esdot.ca/site/2012/fast-rendering-in-air-cached-spritesheets

Comment: I publish my game with GPU and its running very well.Thank you very match for your help.I ask and before solution because my game was running slow but no one tell me about GPU.Thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help. And remember, if you try to use cacheasbitmap on vectors, its easy to hit a point where it gets stuck recaching over and over killing performance....like if u called that on a frame for example. So the best bet if its needed would be to use bitmapData.drawWithQuality to create a bitmapData. The bitmapData is auto cached once. And u can use that one bitmapData cache on any number of bitmaps at the same time.

Comment: Also rendermode direct can be even better, but then you get in to coding stage3D or using starling, which is great but everything is architected a little different